# opencv not found when running py script using user data in ec2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to run darknet on an ec2 instance with ubuntu 18.04.
I have installed opencv3.2 using apt and also buut opencv 4.5 from source.
My detection script seems to be working fine when i run the script directly from inside the instance. However, when i try to automate it and run it using user data on startup, i get the following error in the cloud-init-outpt.log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "strawberry_count_new.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
Cloud-init v. 21.3-1-g6803368d-0ubuntu1~18.04.4 running 'modules:final' at Thu, 06 Jan 2022 02:31:30 +0000. Up 14.85 seconds.
2022-01-06 02:31:41,954 - cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
2022-01-06 02:31:41,955 - util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.py'>) failed
```

Comment: User Data scripts run as the `root` user. Is it possible that you installed the libraries as a different Linux user, so it isn't available when run as `root`?

Comment: How do i check if its installed as root? And if its not, how do i change that?

Comment: You could change to root with `sudo su -` and then try running the script.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The opencv that i needed for the root user to access the library was installed with the command

```
sudo apt-get install python3-opencv
```